# SQL Server not granting equal amount of connections for each connecting webserver?

Tags: sql-server, performance, connection-pooling

I'm responsible for migrating an existing software application to our application. This is something which needs to get done in 24 hours but I'm facing some issues. I'm trying to pin out why some things are slow.

My setup;
SQL Server 2008 R2 and 7 identical VM's. Each VM has about 7 WCF services (normal WCF, but also Worfklow service) running.

When my migration is running, I can see in SQL Server that 1 specific VM has more connections towards SQL server. I use following query for this:

```
SELECT des.program_name,des.login_name,des.host_name,
--der.database_id,
COUNT(des.session_id) [Connections]
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions des
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections DEC
ON des.session_id = DEC.session_id
WHERE des.is_user_process = 1
--AND des.status != ’running’
GROUP BY des.program_name,des.login_name,des.host_name
--,der.database_id
HAVING COUNT(des.session_id) > 2
ORDER BY COUNT(des.session_id) DESC
```

My output is the following:

```
program_name    login_name  host_name   Connections
.Net SqlClient Data Provider    CONSQL3\Administrator   VM1 120
.Net SqlClient Data Provider    CONSQL3\Administrator   VM5 43
.Net SqlClient Data Provider    CONSQL3\Administrator   VM2 41
.Net SqlClient Data Provider    CONSQL3\Administrator   VM7     39
.Net SqlClient Data Provider    CONSQL3\Administrator   VM4     39
.Net SqlClient Data Provider    CONSQL3\Administrator   VM6 39
.Net SqlClient Data Provider    CONSQL3\Administrator   VM3 38
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query  CONSQL3\bent    CONSQL3 23
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  CONSQL3\bent    CONSQL3 5
```

I have to ability to monitor the processing for each VM and I can see that VM1 is in fact processing much faster. VM1 is also the first VM in the migration which starts up and begins to use the database. Is it correct to say that the other VM's are running slower because they dont use the connection pool as optimal as possible? Is VM1 too greedy on the connections?

Each VM has the same Min Pool Size and Max Pool Size settings in the connection string...

Does SQL have some kind of limitation on giving connections? Do I need to tweak some setting? Are there specific performance counters that I should look into to find what is causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is not limiting the amount of connections. Therefore there is no "granting". Everybody can come and open one. You just have one particularly greedy web-server.

Analyze the server to see why so many connections are open. Are many requests running concurrently? Are connections not closed or disposed after use?